# Intersection of two intermediate fields of degree 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Can someone clarify the following thing I've been wondering about today:
If we have a tower of fields [image]

where $K$ and $F$ are distinct and $L/N$ finite Galois, does this force $K/K\cap F$ and $F/K\cap F$ to have degree $2$? $K\cap F$ is the fixed field $L^H$ where $H<Gal(L/N)$ is generated by the two involutions defining $K$ and $F$, but I dont see a reason why that subgroup would be of order $4$ and not a dihedral group of higher order. I've also tried coming up with a counter example but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is right: there's no reason why $[L:K\cap F]$ must equal $4$. For one example (with $N=\Bbb Q$), take $L$ to be the splitting field of $T^3-2$, so that $[L:N]=6$. There are three subfields that can be chosen as $K$ and $F$, but in all cases $K\cap F=\Bbb Q$. See these excellent [notes by Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrexamples.pdf) (Example 3 is more saliant than Example 1) for more details.